# Get data from table(html) except div tag by jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have html code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" class="zebra"> 
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5">
    <div class="paginator">
     <a href="http://some_link">2</a>&nbsp;         
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>   
  <tr> 
   <td><a href="//i_need_only_this_link">some_value</a></td>       
  </tr> 
  <tr>      
   <td><a href="//i_need_only_this_link1">some_value</a></td>       
  </tr> 
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
    <div class="paginator">        
     <a href="http://some_link">2</a>&nbsp;
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

I use Jsoup. How can I get all links except links in div tag?
I try to do something like this, but It doesn't work. Element contains all the links.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Elements tableText = doc.select("table.zebra").not("tr td div.paginator");

for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element td : tableText.select("td a")) {
    System.out.println(td.attr("href")); // http://some_link
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code..

```
Document html = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);

    for (Element e : html.getElementsByTag("a")) {

        if (!"div".equalsIgnoreCase(e.parentNode().nodeName())) {
            System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
        }

    }
```

Here I am checking that the parent node of the anchor element is not div. if it is not div I am printing the url.

Comment: Might be a good idea to use `"abs:href"` though: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls